# Building workspace has encountered a problem in Eclipse luna while creating a Maven Project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am trying to convert Dynamic web project into a maven project and getting this error " *Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'RestDemo'.
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6*  "

It is also showing an error in the Pom.xml file "CoreException: Could not calculate build plan:"

Anyone know a solution to this help me out

Comment: that is a old eclipse version I suggest to upgrade to latest or moving to intellij can help, or vscode, or notepad++ after you finish the upgrade you can try to use eclipse again.